# Performance is getting degraded while opening a webpage in web view in iOS Phonegap

Tags: ipad, cordova, ios5

I have a web app(developed wholly in ASP.Net and C#) deployed on a server. I want to bundle it as a native iOS app using phonegap. 
Actually, all the UI events(like button click etc) are handled in .Net (not in javascript or JQuery Mobile).So I added URL of the web app to web view and got the output in iPad simulator. But I found that the performance of my app is badly affected. The links are not working fine, UI changes suddenly, my validations don't work at all (these many problems found till now). 
Is there any way to increase the performance ? Or do I need to re-develop my app using HTML5,Javascript, jQuery Mobile etc.?

Answer (score 0):

.Net and IOS phonegap doesn't really work the way you want it to. You really need to have your app be standalone in that it takes data in the form of XML or JSON to/from a sever that processes it and sends back more data.

The problem is that .Net handles everything on the page (like you said). You might have to find another option.